# Set value of girdview textbox as command argument of button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here is my grid view

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvClaimBanks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="false" OnRowCommand="grvClaimBanks_RowCommand">
<Columns>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sr.No">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <%#Container.DataItemIndex +1  %>
  </ItemTemplate>                                            
 </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMoratoriumPeroid" runat="server"> 
  </ItemTemplate>                                            
 </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEditProduction" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TextileSLACId") %>' CommandName="EnterClaim" Text="Enter Claim" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>                                           
 </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
```

Now i want to set value of "txtMoratoriumPeroid" as "CommandArgument" of "lnkEditProduction", so i can access that value in Row Command Event of grid view.

Is this possible?

If yes please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are bind the `TextBox` wont give you value change in client side and your `TextBox` seem *empty* on server side. You can get current `row` of command button in RowCommand event and find `TextBox` to take its value.

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
TextBox txtMoratoriumPeroid= row.FindControl("txtMoratoriumPeroid") as TextBox;
if(txtMoratoriumPeroid != null)
{
    //Your code here.
    string txtMoratoriumPeroidText =  txtMoratoriumPeroid.Text; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to give dynamic CommandArgument on the fly.
But you can achieve this by

```
LinkButton lbtnSender = (LinkButton)sender;
TextBox txtMoratoriumPeroid = (TextBox)lbtnSender.Parent.Parent.FindControl("txtMoratoriumPeroid");
string MoratoriumPeroid = txtMoratoriumPeroid.Text;
```